# How to Pass data by using redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to implement `stripe payment gateway integration`. It is working fine with payment success status. I am trying to display to the user when it is failed. But passing failure data to my view is not working. Below is my code.

```
 public function stripepay()
    {
    // some post variables
    try {
    require_once APPPATH."third_party/stripe/init.php";
    //set api key
    $stripe = array(
    "secret_key"      => "sk_test_gSev8A4OJf0F3BXXXXXXXX",
    "publishable_key" => "pk_test_XZZxorO1rYsZTJXXXXXXXX"
    );
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
    // some more code
    }catch ( Stripe\Error\Base $e )
    {
    // Code to do something with the $e exception object when an error occurs.
    $body = $e->getJsonBody();
    $err  = $body['error'];
    $data['failure_response'] = $err;
    $data['response_status'] = $e->getHttpStatus();
    $where = array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id'));
    $payment_info = $this->baseM->getOneRowData('users', $where);
    // this redirct is not working 
    //redirect('service/failure_402'.$data);
    }
    }
```

When it enters into this catch block I am trying to redirect to failue402 view.

```
public function failure_402($data)
{
$where = array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id'));
$payment_info = $this->baseM->getOneRowData('users', $where);
$this->load->view('page_layout/header', $data);
$this->load->view('service/failure_402',$data);
$this->load->view('page_layout/footer', $data); 
}

In the above stripePay() function 
// this redirect is not working 
redirect('service/failure_402'.$data); 
is not working.
```

Please guide me where I am doing the mistake. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use codeigniter flashdata?

Comment: try this redirect('service/failure_402',$data);

Comment: You normally can not pass much data with a HTTP redirect (this is by the HTTP protocol, not a limitation of the PHP framework you use), the data the RFC talks about you pass *with* a redirect is the location to redirect to. You might want to add the $data to the users session so you might be able to re-use later the last set $data.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Comment: If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request, you can do so using the keep_flashdata() method. You can either pass a single item or an array of flashdata items to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use codeigniter session's `set_flashdata()` method

```
{

$body = $e->getJsonBody();
$err  = $body['error'];
$data['failure_response'] = $err;
$data['response_status'] = $e->getHttpStatus();
$where = array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id'));
$payment_info = $this->baseM->getOneRowData('users', $where);

/* EITHER */
$this->session->set_flashdata('failure_response' ,$err);
$this->session->set_flashdata('failure_response' ,$e->getHttpStatus());
/* OR */
 $this->session->set_flashdata($data);

 redirect('service/failure_402');
}
```

In `falure_402()`

```
public function failure_402()
{
   print_r($this->session->flashdata());
   /*OR this way */
  echo $this->session->flashdata('failure_response')
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata